# Android crash when trying to get a view by tag

Tags: java, android, crash

so when I try to get an EditText view by the tag I assigned to it earlier, the app just crashes(and I'm not sure where to get the error log, the console is empty).
The code:

```
`public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listPeopleDisplay;
    private EditText textCurrentName;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private LinearLayout roleCheckboxes;
    private int peopleSize;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listPeopleDisplay = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPlayers);
        listPeopleDisplay.setAdapter(adapter);
        textCurrentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayers);
        peopleSize = 0;
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonAddPlayer) {
            adapter.add(textCurrentName.getText().toString());
            textCurrentName.setText("");
            ++peopleSize;
        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonDoneAddingPlayers) {
            String[] config = new String[peopleSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < peopleSize; i++) {
                config[i] = adapter.getItem(i);
            }
            Configuration.setPeople(config);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_roles);
            roleCheckboxes = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutRoles);
            for (int i = 0; i < Roles.values().length; i++) {
                if (Roles.values()[i] == Roles.MAFIA ||
                        Roles.values()[i] == Roles.YAKUZA ||
                        Roles.values()[i] == Roles.CIVILIAN) {
                    continue;
                }
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                cb.setText(Roles.values()[i].toString());
                cb.setChecked(false);
                cb.setTag(Roles.values()[i]);
                roleCheckboxes.addView(cb);
            }
            EditText mob = new EditText(this);
            mob.setHint("Mafia count");
            mob.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            mob.setTag(Roles.MAFIA);
            roleCheckboxes.addView(mob);
            mob = new EditText(this);
            mob.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            mob.setHint("Yakuza count");
            mob.setTag(Roles.YAKUZA);
            roleCheckboxes.addView(mob);
            mob = new EditText(this);
            mob.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            mob.setHint("Civilian count");
            mob.setTag(Roles.CIVILIAN);
            roleCheckboxes.addView(mob);
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            CheckBox civ = (CheckBox)roleCheckboxes.findViewWithTag(Roles.CIVILIAN);
<!-- the rest is irrelevant-->`
```

It crashes on the last line.

Comment: Assuming you are in Android Studio, do Alt + 6 to see the Logcat

Comment: Cheers, I am so stupid.

Comment: You were ignorant of this one detail, not stupid. You are no longer ignorant of it.

Answer (score 0):

`roleCheckboxes` is set in the `else if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonDoneAddingPlayers)` statement, and you are trying to use it in the third else statement which is out of it's initializing scope.You should have the initialization:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_roles);
roleCheckboxes = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutRoles);
```

and the usage

```
CheckBox civ = (CheckBox)roleCheckboxes.findViewWithTag(Roles.CIVILIAN);
```

in the same scope ( for example in teh same if statement) or you should initialize the `roleCheckboxes` in the `onCreate` method

Comment: I'm switching a layout in the second block, so the third is never triggered before second, which is why I initialize the associated stuff there. If I initialize `roleCheckboxes` in the `onCreate` method, it's null when it's called from the second block. But it's existent when I try to call it in the third, if the initialization happends in the second.

Answer (score 0):

As logcat showed, I was trying to cast a CheckBox to an EditText. I am dumb. Sorry for your time.